# Android Studio 4.0 Gradle build not finished

Tags: android, gradle

I have tried with all the solutions given in this forum, but nothing, I have installed and uninstalled all the versions, now with the 4.0, the installation is fine, I delete the folders. Gradle .android the installation folders, I have tried to create the gradle.properties file and put:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

The internet connection is correct, this happens on the laptop, on the desktop computer, with the same configuration (even the same programs) I have no problem.

I open a new project, an existing one, but nothing, I have tried to clear the cache it throws hours and hours with the Gradle sync started and obviously I cannot do anything.

When I do a clean install, the last one with android 4.0 I create a new project and nothing, Gradley sync started ...... hours and hours. The folders that I delete are when I uninstall, when I install the ide, I don't delete anything

Does not show any errors, just

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 477 ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Please include the text version of your error i.e stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Although in the windows 10 firewall I had the permissions to access the network and the connection test was correct, the firewall did not give it access, I have installed the TinyWall firewall and now everything is fine.
Be very careful with the firewall of windows 10